# Input field width and height: how to change them

Tags: php, drupal, forms, content-management-system

I've never touched drupal's theming layer before, so I apologize for the basic question. I'm trying to change the default width and height for the input fields used in drupal forms.

Is there a generic template that I need to change? or do I have to find everywhere where there's a form, find its template, and change it. Any tips on how to proceed with this?

Comment: Which Drupal version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change all inputs' width you can use pure css. All inputs in drupal have a class called "form-text".

So you can write

```
.form-text{
    width:100px;
}
```

If you really want to wirte your own template - you should look towards the [theme_form_element](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_form_element/6) function.